# back button inside a class large

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap select button and I want to make it large but I can't seem to get the jquery selector correct. I'm trying this below with no luck.

```js
$('.bootstrap-select button').addClass('btn-lg');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control">
  <button title="Male" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="genderId"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Male</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu open">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu">
      <li class="selected" data-original-index="0"><a tabindex="0" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Male</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li data-original-index="1"><a tabindex="0" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Female</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine, the `button` element is correctly given a class of `btn-lg`: https://jsfiddle.net/mvcj7n6a/

Comment: I've taken the liberty to add jQuery, bootstrap, and your jQuery call to your question.  Only problem is that it all seems to work, just like BenM notes.  I don't see what the issue is unless your example is missing some key code.

Comment: Do you have some sort of jQuery involved that removes the `bootstrap-select` class from the DOM?

Comment: technically it's coming from a asp.net razor html.enumdropdownlistfor so there might be some weird rendering

Comment: @user1186050 does the javascript console output any errors?

Comment: It could then be how your bundling is set up. Make sure too that you're doing your jQuery in a `ready` function.

Comment: @BenM - Why does your fiddle work and mine not?  https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=E6qyz5wONu

Comment: if I put the addClass's code at the top of the js file it doesn't work, but if I put the addClass's code in a on click event it works! do I need to wait for selectpicker to finish loading? if so how do I do this?

Comment: if the code is being created dynamically you should refer to the elements like this: `$(document).find('.bootstrap-select button').addClass('btn-lg');`

Comment: that doesn't work. the only thing I could get to work was putting it inside a selectpicker event $('.selectpicker').on('loaded.bs.select', function (e) {
        $('.bootstrap-select button').addClass('btn-lg');
        $('.bootstrap-select').addClass('input-lg');
    });

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that seems to work is by putting the add class changes inside a select event

```
$('.selectpicker').on('loaded.bs.select', function (e) {
        $('.bootstrap-select button').addClass('btn-lg');
        $('.bootstrap-select').addClass('input-lg');
    });
```